# jq: error: X/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to extract value from the bellow JSON:

```
% export test='{"a-b-c":"x-y-z"}'
% echo $test
{"a-b-c":"x-y-z"}
% echo $test | jq .a-b-c
jq: error: b/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.a-b-c
jq: error: c/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.a-b-c
jq: 2 compile errors
% echo $test | jq '."a-b-c"'
"x-y-z"
%
```

while the last line "works", my end goal is to have shell script and substitute "a-b-c" parameter with variable, however due to I must use single quotes, the actual value isn't being passed..

```
% export var1=a-b-c
% echo $var1
a-b-c
% echo $test | jq '."$var1"'
null
%
```

Please advise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--arg` option to initialize a jq variable with a shell variable's value.

```bash
jq --arg key "$var1" '.[$key]'
```

See [Invoking jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq) and scroll down to `--arg`

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work:

```
% echo $test | jq ".\"$var1\""
"x-y-z"
%
```

Thanks!